# ActiveRecord: query not using correct type condition for STI subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, development-environment, sti

I have a set of STI subclasses inheriting from a `User` base class. I am finding that under certain conditions inside a subclass' definition, queries on the subclasses do not correctly use the `type` condition.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
end

class Admin < User
  Rails.logger.info "#{name}: #{all.to_sql}"
  # ...
end
```

When loading the Rails console in development, it does what I would expect:

```
Admin: SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`type` IN ('Admin')
```

But when hitting the app (localhost / pow), it is missing the `type` condition and I get this:

```
Admin: SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`
```

But not from the app when when deployed to a staging server:

```
Admin: SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`type` IN ('Admin')
```

This, of course, causes any queries executed here in the dev app (but not from the console) to be incorrect. Specifically, I am trying to preload a (small) cache of existing db values in order to create a few helpful methods based on those data. Without the type scope, the cache is obviously incorrect!

From the same location (`Admin`), we get the following confusing contradiction:

```
[11] pry(Admin)> Admin.finder_needs_type_condition?
=> true
[12] pry(Admin)> Admin.send(:type_condition).to_sql
=> "`users`.`type` IN ('Admin')"
[13] pry(Admin)> Admin.all.to_sql
=> "SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`"
```

Further, I defined a throwaway subclass `Q < User` inside the `user.rb` file. I logged `Q.all.to_sql` from its definition, from the definition of `Admin`, and from a view. In that order, we get:

```
From Q: Q: SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`type` IN ('Q')
From Admin: Q: SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`
From View: Q: SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`type` IN ('Q')
```

**What could cause, in the first line of the `Admin` subclass definition in admin.rb, any subclass of `User` to fail to use its `type_condition`?**

This is causing development tests to fail, and so is of some consequence to my app. What on earth could be causing this difference in behavior? Can anyone think of a more general way around the problem of not having the STI conditions defined on a subclass during its definition *only in the development app environment*?

Answer (score 4):

One difference between production and development is the following line inside of the application configuration:

```
# config/environments/development.rb
config.eager_load = false
```

vs.

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.eager_load = true
```

So on your production environment, all your clases are loaded when the app is started.
When `eager_load` is set to false, Rails will try to autoload your `User` class when you first load the `Admin` class.

Given that, I'd assume that you have another class or module named `User`.

FYI: ActiveRecord has a method called `finder_needs_type_condition?`. It should return true for a class that uses STI:

```
User.finder_needs_type_condition? # should be false
Admin.finder_needs_type_condition? # should be true
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I get the eager load difference, but it's still mysterious why the issue is *not* present in the dev console but *is* present in the dev app (when I use localhost / pow). The `finder_needs_type_condition?` method is good to know about: yet, it returns `true` when I pry from the app while still giving me `"SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`"` as in the question. Relatedly, I found the private method `type_condition`, which, when calling `to_sql` on, yields ``"`users`.`type` IN ('Admin')"``. So something is clearly broke.

Comment: Related, I was **not** able to replicate this behavior on another STI subclass of a completely different base class, so this seems to have something to do with the `User` class specifically. Progress...

Comment: One more update: I've commented *everything* in my `User` base class out other than the class declaration itself, and the issue persists. So I can't see what could be special about this class now, or how whatever is causing this issue goes away after the class definition is finished.

Comment: Ok so thanks to your pointers I think I at least have a workaround now: when loading the data, use `self.finder_needs_type_condition? ? self.where(type_condition) : self.all`. Ugly, not sure why it's necessary, and leads to a superfluous `WHERE` for other STI classes that don't have this issue. So pretty undesirable to actually use this code in a gem. But I'm not sure what a better solution may be at this point.

Comment: @andrew, just found a page that explains autoloading with STI: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoloading-and-sti . It suggests to explicitely `require` subclasses...

Comment: Thanks @andiba! It's 100% not clear to me why, but that does fix the issue. That is recommended to allow the base class (`User`) to be aware of its subclasses (`Admin`), but how does requiring the `admin.rb` file from `user.rb` fix an error that is occurring inside `admin.rb` itself? Very puzzling. Since I'm doing this from a gem, too, the best I can do is put it in the docs that you should do this if you're using the gem from a STI subclass. In any case, this is an effective solution, it would seem -- though I would love to know *why* it's an effective solution!!

Answer (score 1):

Currently, any `User` will have an empty `:type` column. Could this is be a problem?

Have you tried to make `User` a super class? E.g.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Admin < User; end
class NormalUser < User; end
```

Comment: Correct me if Im misunderstanding something, I've never used `abstract_class` in Ruby / Rails. Reading the docs, I see that `abstract_class` should be set to `true` if I do *not* want the subclasses to use the same table name. But I do, so I'm not sure this is correct for my use case. When I try it, I get what you might then expect: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'threeplay_development.admins' doesn't exist`. What did you mean by any `User` will have an empty `type` column? The `users` table is populated correctly, I just need to load that data when the app starts.

Comment: Upps, you're right with the `abstract_class`: That was nonsense. However, the **empty** `:type` column problem. When you do a `User.create( {attributes....})` without specifying `:type` it gets a `nil` value. The same with `Admin.create(...)` sets automatically `type = 'Admin'`.

Comment: Yep, thanks for the response. The data already exists and has the `type` column populated (current 13k total `User`s, among them 23 `Admin`s). Here I'm just reading from the table using `Admin.all` (or `self.all` inside the `Admin` class' definition), and it is not generating an appropriate `WHERE` clause under the specific condition outlined above.