# .all returning an empty relation with parent and child classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance

I have 3 classes which inherit from each, like:
`Puppy` << `Dog` << `Animal`

I have 3 instances of `puppy` in my database.

When i run `Dog.all` i want to see a list of all puppies (as well as any future `dogs`)

`Dog.all` does not return any `puppies`. (it just returns an empty relation)

However if i then run `Puppy.all` (which returns all 3 puppies), and then run `Dog.all` straight after, it does return the 3 puppies.
So there might be some caching happening?

So my question is, how can i call `Dog.all` and return the 3 puppies.

Apologies if this doesnt make sense. Happy to provide more information

Comment: Is that order correct?  `Animal` inherits from `Dog`, which inherits from `Puppy`, so puppy is the top?

Comment: apologies, have updated @RockwellRice

Comment: @Ben can you post yr models classes ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36992467/activerecord-query-not-using-correct-type-condition-for-sti-subclass) answer your problem.
You need to set the eager_load to true in your environment file:

```
# config/environments/development.rb
config.eager_load = false
```

Answer (score -1):

Loooks like you're implementing STI. I'd say, initially, take a look at https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html

Assuming that you've `Puppy#type` column you need to query parent class, like:

`Puppy.where(type: ["Dog", nil])` - as far as I remember root class for STI will not provide a type value.

or your could write query as Max mentioned - `Dog.where(type: ["Dog", nil])`